# Material-UI How to set minWidth and maxWidth of MenuItem (popover) according to the width of the select component

Tags: css, reactjs, width, material-ui, html-select

The width of the popover, to be precise. No matter how long the text of menu item is, I want the width of the popover always the same as the select component. Set the ***autoWidth*** to ***true*** or ***false*** is not helping.

following are code for the select component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import OutlinedInput from '@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
}));

function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    age: '',
  });

  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
  }, []);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues(oldValues => ({
      ...oldValues,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }));
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} htmlFor="outlined-age-simple">
          Age
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={values.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput labelWidth={labelWidth} name="age" id="outlined-age-simple" />}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: Check if  calc() function of CSS is helpful.

Comment: You want the SelectInput width to have the width of the widest MenuItem? Or all the MenuItems to have the width that you fixed for the SelectInput?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting an explicit width on the menu items that is the same as the width for the form control.

Below is an example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MuiMenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const selectWidth = 150;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    width: selectWidth
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

const useMenuItemStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  menuItem: {
    width: selectWidth
  }
}));

function MenuItem(props) {
  const classes = useMenuItemStyles(props);
  return <MuiMenuItem className={classes.menuItem} {...props} />;
}

function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    age: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues(oldValues => ({
      ...oldValues,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={values.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          inputProps={{
            name: "age",
            id: "age-simple"
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SimpleSelect;
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

If you want the width of the `Select` to be dynamic based on the width of the widest menu item, then the solution is a fair amount more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Menu by default have auto width and height
menu adjust it's width and height according to child ListItems

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
createStyles({
    listItem:{
        maxWidth:150,
        minWidth:100,
        padding: theme.spacing(2)
    }
}),
```

);